# Update color in different marker in Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I need to achieve the scatter plot with color, size, symbol and text.

My goal is setting text with different color variable from scatter plot.

The color is from Species

The size is from Sepal.Width

The shape is from shape_1

The text is from Sepal.Width with color from color_1

If I run the first chunk code, it is correct.

Then if I add_trace to display the text, the color messed up

Any idea will be great

```
dt <- iris
dt$shape_1 <- c("Yes","No")
dt$color_1 <- c("Medium","Large","Small")


plot_ly(dt,
        x=1:nrow(iris),
        y=~Sepal.Length,
        type="scatter",
        mode='markers',
        color=~Species,
        colors = c("#4477AA","#DDCC77","#CC6677"),
        size = ~Sepal.Width, 
        symbol = ~shape_1,
        symbols = c("triangle-up", "circle"),
        inherit = F,
        sizes = c(10, 100) * 10)
```

```
dt <- iris
dt$shape_1 <- c("Yes","No")
dt$color_1 <- c("Medium","Large","Small")


plot_ly(dt,
        x=1:nrow(iris),
        y=~Sepal.Length,
        type="scatter",
        mode='markers',
        color=~Species,
        colors = c("#4477AA","#DDCC77","#CC6677"),
        size = ~Sepal.Width, 
        symbol = ~shape_1,
        symbols = c("triangle-up", "circle"),
        inherit = F,
        sizes = c(10, 100) * 10) %>%
add_trace(type="scatter",
          mode = "text",
          text=~Sepal.Width,
          textposition = "top right",
          color = ~color_1,
          colors = c("black","green","blue"),
          textfont = list(size = 10)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `text` argument in the `add_trace()` function to use the same color scale as the rest of the markers, also the colour codes should match, that's where the issue is.

```
plot_ly(
  dt,
  x = 1:nrow(iris),
  y =  ~ Sepal.Length,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = 'markers',
  color =  ~ Species,
  colors = c("#4477AA", "#DDCC77", "#CC6677"),
  size = ~ Sepal.Width,
  symbol = ~ shape_1,
  symbols = c("triangle-up", "circle"),
  inherit = F,
  sizes = c(10, 100) * 10
) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "text",
    text =  ~ Sepal.Width,
    textposition = "top right",
    color = ~ Species,
    colors = c("#4477AA", "#DDCC77", "#CC6677"),
    textfont = list(size = 10
    )
  )
```

Comment: The problem is I need to assign the different color variable for text variable

Comment: I modified 'add_trace()' by adding 
'marker = list(
            color = ifelse(dt$color_1 == "Medium", "black",
                           ifelse(dt$color_1 == "Large", "green", "blue"))
          )'

Hope this helps